# Reporte que muestra todos los campos en BD, hasta campos NULL

Tags: php, html, excel, phpexcel

Este es mi código donde se realiza una exportación de todos mis datos almacenado en  mi BD (reportes), **pero en mi BD tengo campos nulos y al bajar el reporte de excel me baja todos los datos que están almacenados en la BD y solo necesito que muestre en dicho reporte solo con los registros que necesito y no que me muestre también las lineas donde están mis campos nulos**

Asi esta modelada mi BD:

```
id_Control Primaria  
nombre  
ap_paterno  
ap_materno      
NSS 
CURP    
RFC     
fecha_nac   
id_puesto FK  
idpuesto_semanal FK NULL  
id_area FK 
idarea_semanal FK  NULL
idctg_turno FK  
idctg_empresa FK    
id_nomina FK
```

```html
<?php

 require 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
 require("connect_db.php");
 $sql = "SELECT id_Control, nombre, ap_paterno, ap_materno, NSS, CURP, RFC, fecha_nac, idpuesto_semanal, idarea_semanal, idctg_turno, idctg_empresa FROM trabajador";
 $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
 
 $fila = 2;
 
 $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel ();
 $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Codigos de programacion")->
 setDescription("Reporte de Trabajador");
 
 $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("Reporte_Trabajador");
 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('H')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('I')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('J')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('K')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('L')->setAutoSize(true);
 
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Numero de Control');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', 'Nombre');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C1', 'Apellido Paterno');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D1', 'Apellido Materno');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E1', 'NSS');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F1', 'CURP');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G1', 'RFC');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H1', 'Fecha de Nacimiento');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I1', 'Puesto');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J1', 'Area');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K1', 'Turno');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L1', 'Empresa');
 
 
 while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
 {
  
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$fila, $row['id_Control'] ); 
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$fila, $row['nombre'] ); 
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$fila, $row['ap_paterno'] );
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$fila, $row['ap_materno'] );
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$fila, $row['NSS'] );
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$fila, $row['CURP'] );
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$fila, $row['RFC'] );
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$fila, $row['fecha_nac'] );
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$fila, $row['idpuesto_semanal'] );
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$fila, $row['idarea_semanal'] );
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$fila, $row['idctg_turno'] );
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$fila, $row['idctg_empresa'] ); 
 
 $fila++;
 }


 header("Content-Type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
 header('Content-Disposition: attechment;filename="Reporte_Trabajador_Semanal.xlsx"');
 header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
 
 $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
 $objWriter->save('php://output');
 
 
?>
```

Comment: Carlos tu pregunta no es clara. Dices que no quieres los campos nulos, pero ¿qué campos nulos? ¿qué significa que no los quieres, que quieres que se omita la fila entera cuando un determinado campo o unos determinados campos sea nulos? ¿significa que en vez de `NULL` quieres que te muestre esa columna en blanco? Como ves, faltan muchos detalles para comprender lo que quieres.

Comment: Buenos dias A.Cedano ¿qué significa que no los quieres, que quieres que se omita la fila entera cuando un determinado campo o unos determinados campos sea nulos? Si en mi BD tengo campos nulos para ese registro quiero que no me importe toda la fila ya que es innecesario  por que me muestra en blanco esos campos nulos para ese registro

Comment: Carlos todavía no entiendo... ¿lo que quieres es que si todas las columnas de la fila son nulas no importe esa fila?  ¿que no importe la fila cuando el campo `X`  o los campos `X` e `Y` sean nulos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te refieres al registro completo este null, entonces tienes que cambiar tu query.

Este es tu query inicia:

```
 $sql = "SELECT id_Control, nombre, ap_paterno, ap_materno, NSS, CURP, 
 RFC, fecha_nac, 
 idpuesto_semanal, idarea_semanal, idctg_turno, idctg_empresa FROM 
 trabajador"
```

Ejemplo si no quisieras que salgan los que su nombre sea null seria asi:

```
 $sql = "SELECT id_Control, nombre, ap_paterno, ap_materno, NSS, CURP, 
 RFC, fecha_nac, 
 idpuesto_semanal,
 idarea_semanal, idctg_turno, idctg_empresa 
 FROM trabajador **where nombre is not null**"
```

Y asi por cada campo, esto omitira el registro completo si tiene el campo null.

Comment: siempre que pongas código dale formato, ya que en texto se ve complejo de entender

Comment: Muchas gracias, es justamente lo que necesitaba. Saludos